# Does the Camera Module for Kivy Allow Custom Framerates?

Tags: kivy

I'm an artist looking to make an app that utilizes the camera on an Android or Iphone device to display a stereoscopic video feed at 1  to 5 frames per second. Python/Kivy is what I (sort of) know, so I'm starting there. Does the `Camera` module in Kivy support inputting a custom framerate? The existing documentation doesn't seem to say.

(Also very open to simpler ways to accomplish this/existing applications).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't directly have a property to set for that, but it should be very easy to achieve. Off the top of my head, you could render the widget in an Fbo and only redraw the Fbo at the rate you require, but there's probably a neater solution.

Probably a bigger problem will be that the Camera support is not that robust, make sure you prototype first to understand what works and what doesn't - or at least what needs more custom work to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This led me to dive into what an fbo is; time to get coding. How can I redraw it though?

Comment: Fbos are rendered when you ask, I can't remember the api.